# Validation for Angular's custom form array stays as PENDING for async validators

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, validation, formarray

I have a custom postal code async validator, that also works for Template Driven forms.

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appAsyncPostalCode]',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, useExisting: AsyncPostalCodeValidatorDirective, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class AsyncPostalCodeValidatorDirective implements AsyncValidator {
  public validate(
    control: AbstractControl
  ): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return this.postalCodeValidator()(control);
  }

  public postalCodeValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      const postalCodePattern = /^\d{5}$/;
      if (control.value && postalCodePattern.test(control.value)) {
        return checkPostalCodeXHR(control.value).pipe(
          map(name => null),
          catchError(() => {
            if (control.value) {
              control.markAsTouched();
            }
            return of({ postalCodeInvalid: true });
          })
        );
      } else {
        return of(control.value ? { postalCode: true } : null);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

And a custom implementation to use Form Array in Template Driven forms.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-array-input',
  templateUrl: './array-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./array-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: ArrayInputComponent, multi: true },
    { provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ArrayInputComponent, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class ArrayInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AsyncValidator {
  @Input() public name!: string;

  @ContentChild(ArrayItemDirective, { static: true })
  public itemTemplate!: ArrayItemDirective;

  public get value() {
    return this.array.value;
  }

  private array = new FormArray([]);
  public controlIds: symbol[] = [];

  constructor(
    @Optional() @Host() parent: ControlContainer,
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    if (parent) {
      this.array.setParent(parent.control as any);
    }
    this.array.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.onChange(value);
      this.onTouch();
    });
  }

  public validate() {
    return combineLatest(this.array.controls.map(c => c.statusChanges)).pipe(
      startWith(this.array.controls.map(c => c.status)),
      filter(() => !this.array.controls.some(c => c.pending)),
      map(() => (this.array.valid ? null : { array: true })),
      take(1)
    );
  }

  private onChange: (val?: any) => void = () => {};
  private onTouch: () => void = () => {};

  public registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }

  public add() {
    this.controlIds.push(Symbol());
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }

  public removeAt(index: number) {
    this.controlIds.splice(index, 1);
    this.array.removeAt(index);
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }

  public bindItem(item: ArrayValueDirective) {
    const isNew = item.index >= this.array.length;
    if (!isNew) {
      const value = this.array.at(item.index).value;
      item.setValue(value);
    }

    this.array.setControl(item.index, item.control, { emitEvent: isNew });
  }

  public writeValue(newArray: any[] | null): void {
    if (!equal(this.value, newArray)) {
      this.array.clear({ emitEvent: false });
      this.controlIds.splice(0);

      if (newArray) {
        for (const val of newArray) {
          this.array.push(new FormControl(val), { emitEvent: false });
          this.controlIds.push(Symbol());
        }
      }
    }

    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

The problem is that `ArrayInputComponent > validate` is called when the value changes, but the control's `statusChanges` never fires, even though the status change from `PENDING` to `VALID`. Because of this the array control stays in `PENDING` and the whole form is not valid.

For now the only workaround I could find is to check the validity of the parent component in the next tick after the async validator completes

```js
...
return checkPostalCodeXHR(control.value).pipe(
  map(name => {
    setTimeout(() => control.parent?.updateValueAndValidity());
    return null;
  }),
  catchError(() => {
    if (control.value) {
      control.markAsTouched();
    }
    setTimeout(() => control.parent?.updateValueAndValidity());
    return of({ postalCodeInvalid: true });
  })
);
...
```

I'm aware that in some occasions Angular's sets the `emitEvent` to `false` for updates, but also that did some changes to fix this for async validators (https://github.com/profanis/angular/commit/bae96682e7d5ea1942c72583e7d68a24507c1a5a).

Does someone have a solution for this?
It could be that I'm declaring something incorrectly, or that I should check the validity of the array in some other way?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I made a Stackblitz with the issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-form-array-jf9h5v.
It's better to check the browser's console than the Stackblitz one. You can see how the VALID status for the first control doesn't get emitted, but if you check the control log in the console, which gets evaluated in expansion, the status is VALID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fork of the added Stackblitz solves the issue.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-form-array-jf9h5v-uh3t4x

It seems that for the FormArray's controls, `statusChanges` doesn't emit the new status. But the array's `statusChanges` does. This can be used to properly validate the array.

```js
  public validate() {
    return this.array.statusChanges.pipe(
      startWith(this.array.status),
      filter(() => !this.array.pending),
      map(() => (this.array.valid ? null : { array: true })),
      take(1)
    );
  }
```